Gradle configuration phase
I need to run a file copy between jacocoTestReport and jacocoTestCoverageVerification. the following seemed to work. but what I observed is that the following two lines (println) ran during Configuration phase while the lines in between (copy and rename) ran during Execution phase. Why does it behave this way?
tasks.register("copyTask", Copy) {

    doFirst {
        System.out.println("copyRenameFile begin...")
    }

    System.out.println fileTree(include:['**/*.xml'], dir:"build/reports/jacoco/test").collect()    <---
    from("build/reports/jacoco/test")
    into("/repository/build/reports/jacoco/test")
    include("jacocoTest.xml")
    rename('jacocoTest.xml', 'jacocoTestReport.xml')
    System.out.println fileTree(include:['**/*.xml'], dir:"build/reports/jacoco/test").collect()   <---

    doLast {
        System.out.println("copyRenameFile end")
    }
}

copyTask.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
jacocoTestCoverageVerification.dependsOn copyTask
check.dependsOn copyTask

Output:
1:20:42 PM: Executing 'build'...


\> Configure project :

[]                          <----

[]                          <----

\> Task :bootBuildInfo

\> Task :compileJava
...
\> Task :jacocoTestReport

\> Task :copyTask
copyRenameFile begin...
copyRenameFile end

\> Task :jacocoTestCoverageVerification
\> Task :check
\> Task :build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 39s
11 actionable tasks: 11 executed
1:22:22 PM: Execution finished 'build'.


Which plugins are you using in your build?

You might want to visit the docs on using Gradle Tasks for more information behind why it works this way.
